# How to decrease BLE connection Interval time in android

Tags: android, api, bluetooth

I am developing a BLE application on Sam sung s5 using Android BLE API. I have a few questions/doubts:

For sending single packet through BLE it is taking 37ms, what are changes we need to do , to reduce it to 7.4 ms in Android application side.

Comment: @user2450263, think you are so smart?

Comment: @metalurgus no, would have silently down-voted question and your answer, or voted to close the question. I saw that the user is new to SO, and indicated that it would be better to research a bit and then post questions, rather than just asking "what" or "how" directly. No issues removing the comment, by the way, your answer should be a comment , maybe (?)

Comment: @user2450263 ok I see you have no idea about Bluetooth. So please don't waste my time with your useless and long comments.

Answer (score 1):

it's imposible. 37ms is a very good time. It's really imposible by technical limitations because of advertisement interval frequency, which can't be lower than 20ms

Comment: and what's wrong with the answer? It is **correct**. If you know better, then where is your *better* answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you speak about advertising interval it can't be under 20 ms due to BLE specification. If you are speaking about connection interval when you are transfering packet (after a connection) it can't be under 7.5 ms due to BLE specification. However, it depends on BLE chip. For example, Nordic Semiconductor supports the minimum value as 7.5 ms. On the device (smartphone) side it depends on the BLE chip on it. However, it's possible that the upper layer (in Android OS) avoid to use the minimum value supported by the hardware BLE chip.

Remember that faster packet transmission means lower battery duration. The radio module is off only for 7.5 ms and then is reactivated.

Paolo.